# JQuery color picker change hex value

Tags: jquery, hex, color-picker

I'm using this colorpicker http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker and am trying to capture the hex value so that I can use it on the server side to store the selected color.

I'm unable to get the selected color after changing the default color.

Here is my code:

```
 var currentHex = '#0000ff';
            alert(currentHex);
            $('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
                color: currentHex,
                onShow: function (colpkr) {
                    $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
                    return false;
                },
                onHide: function (colpkr) {
                    $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
                    return false;
                },
                onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                    // every time a new colour is selected, this function is called
                    currentHex = hex;
                    $('#mycolor').val = currentHex;
                }
            });
```

Html:

```
<div id="colorSelector"><div style="background-color: rgb(62, 62, 189); "></div></div>
<input type="text" maxlength="6" size="6" id="mycolor" value="00ff00">
```

Here is my **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRWEd/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#mycolor').val = currentHex; //wrong syntax
```

should be

```
$('#mycolor').val(currentHex);
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRWEd/4/)

Comment: @ocanal-Thank you for your quick reply.This is what exactly I need:)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentHex = '#0000ff';
    $('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
        color: currentHex,
        onShow: function(colpkr) {
            $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
            return false;
        },
        onHide: function(colpkr) {
            $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
            return false;
        },
        onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb) {
            $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
            alert(hex);
            $('#mycolor').val(currentHex);
        }
    });

});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are going for?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zHkxT/)